# How to loop multiple data to create multiple csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

Hey guys I need to loop this 3 sample data:

```
data_1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
data_2 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
data_3 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

so that they will all be converted into csv files and I wont repeat this code 3 times.

```
csvfile = open("data_1", "w", newline="")
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")

for i in data_1:
   csv_writer.writerow(i)
csvfile.close()
```

but i do not know how to do it. Please help thanks!

This is the full code:

```
Import csv

data_1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
data_2 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
data_3 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

csvfile = open("data_1", "w", newline="")
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")

for i in data_1:
   csv_writer.writerow(i)
csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (of many) to do this is to use a dictionary and iterate through it generating one file for each of your sets of data.

```
datasets = dict(data_1=data_1, data_2=data_2, data_3=data_3)
for name, data in datasets.items():
    csvfile = open(name, "w", newline="")
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for i in data:
       csvwriter.writerow(i)
    csvfile.close()
```

(I didn't try out your csvwriter code and assume it's already working for the one block of data.)

Answer (score 0):

One way (of many) to do this is to define a function that does the writing to csv, and then call that function with any data you want.

```
def write_to_csv(data, filename):
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        with csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",") as csvwriter:
            for row in data:
                csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Then, you can call this function like so:

```
write_to_csv(data_1, "data_1.csv")
write_to_csv(data_2, "data_2.csv")
write_to_csv(data_3, "data_3.csv")
```

If you have a whole bunch of `data_*` variables, you should read [How do I create a variable number of variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/843953) for a better way to handle all of those `data_*` variables.